# Не присваивает значение в char переменную

Tags: java, char

В переменную типа char c  хочу записать значение . Однако компилятор выдает ошибку unclosed character literal:

```
public static char charExpression(int a) {        
    char c = '\';
    return c;
}
```

Comment: да, потому что спецсимволы надо экранировать. пробуйте так : char c = '\\';

Answer (score 0):

Потому что надо '\\' вместо '\'! Это же специальный символ, его надо удваивать.